# opencart 1.5 вывод отзывов на отдельную страницу

Tags: php, opencart

Нужно вывести кастомные отзывы на отдельную страницу, и чтобы эти отзывы администратор мог добавлять через админку. Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого уже есть модули.
Вот [один](https://opencartforum.com/files/file/2888-otzyvy-o-magazine-ocenka-magazinu-oc-15-i-oc-2/) из них.

Если не хотите использовать сторонние модули, напишите свой.
Нужно создать таблицу в базе, создать model, view, controller и языковый пакет в admin(админке) и catalog(пользовательской стороне).
Если не позволяют знания, попробуйте разобрать какой-то готовый модуль, посмотреть как они работают. 
Так-же попробуйте почитать о том как создавать свои [модули](https://opencartforum.com/files/file/2888-otzyvy-o-magazine-ocenka-magazinu-oc-15-i-oc-2/).

Comment: Спасибо, все предельно четко и ясно. Только ссылка вроде не туда ведет

Comment: Поправил:) Извиняюсь